# Make a call with a gMSA account

Tags: powershell, windows-container, gmsa

My system administrator made a gMSA for me to use with my work with containers.  I am able to do the simple things with it (like test that it is working correctly). 
 But I cannot figure out how to use it for more than hosting and such.

**How can I use the gMSA to make a call to a service that does Active Directory integration?**

The specifics of my scenario are this:

- I have a ProGet server that hosts a Chocolatey feed for me.  It is setup to be integrated with Active Directory.
- When I run a `choco search` command using my own machine, it works just fine.
- when I run the same `choco search` command from the container it fails with an error:

  ```
   Not able to contact source 'http://MyLibrary/nuget/Chocolatey/'. Error was Expected an absolute, well formed http URL without a query or fragment.
  ```
- If i run `curl MyLibrary/nuget/Chocolatey` I get a valid response, though the page content says access is denied.  (So I know I can connect, but cannot authenticate.)
- I have added my gMSA user to my proget Chocolatey feed

Comment: Did you configure your container to use GMSA?